# Cipolla's algorithm for finding square roots - why is first step fast?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm reading about the Cipolla algorithm to find the square root of some quadratic residue n in $\mathbb{F}_p$ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm.

The first step of the algorithm is to keep picking a random $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ until you find one with $a^2 - n$ not a square.

The couple of references I've found online suggest this should be quick, and that about half of all possible $a$ will satisfy this. I can't see why this is necessarily the case, as the distribution of $a^2 - n$ isn't going to be uniform across $\mathbb{F}_p$, so might not be distributed as an even split across quadratic residues / non-residues.

Can anyone give me a hint as to why this holds? Thanks.

Comment: @vadim123: Right, but the distribution of $a^2$ can't be uniform. I agree that if I was picking any element uniformly then the probability of being a square would be very close to 1/2 (as half of all non-zero elements are quadratic residues), but I'm constrained here to picking values in the form $a^2 - n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a nonzero square $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ (with $p$ odd), the number of pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$ satisfying $a^2-n=b^2$ is equal to $p-1$, as can be seen by putting $x=a+b$, $y=a-b$. From this one can deduce that the number of $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $a^2-n$ is a square is equal to $(p+1)/2$. So trying random values of $a$, we succeed with about $2$ tries.